# openpyxl - I need read in Excel file - modify content but preserve cell COLORS for all cells

Tags: python, openpyxl

So far everything I tried along the line:

```
cell_A1 = worksheet['A1']
cell_fill = cell_A1.fill.fgColor.index
```

or:

```
cell_fill = cell_A1.fill.start_color.index
```

yields obviously WRONG answers - no matter how I set the color of A1 cell I get same '0000FFFF'. 
If that is a known issue then I would appreciate a warning - I am mainly using OpenPyxl because I need to read in comments but if there is a problem with reading or writing format then I will use OpenPyxl just for comments and do the rest with another package(s).

Comment: Are you trying to fill color for all the cells in worksheet A1?

Comment: No - I am trying to get the background colors for all the in the input Excel file - I will have to do some operation that will require splitting rows - one row will generate multiple (row dependent) number of rows in the output file. And for consistency I want to preserve colors - so all those new rows have same type of colors (eg column 12 set to light blue) as the original row. The current colors do not follow any patterns.

Comment: If you're trying to set the background colour then why aren't you using `fill.bgColor`?

Comment: I just tried it on my python and I get a different result for each cell that has a different color. you're either not saving the sheet before retesting or doing something wrong. (I used `cell.fill.fgColor.rgb`)

Comment: As I explain - the issue is to create new Excel spreadsheet for old one - with preserving of formatting and comments (hence OpenPyXL choice for comments handling). 
I am not yet at a point of setting colors yet - I try to get them from the cells in original file.

Comment: I think I found the culprit - I was running script on Excel file in old format (.xls) - when I saved it as .xlsx I see the change indeed.

Comment: So as a followup - I get fill color on the original cell as: [code](cell.fill.fgColor.value) - for example [code](8) now I want to set the fill on the copy of the cell to same value using sth like [code](new_cell.fill = PatternFill(fgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type = "solid")) . So how do I pass correct value to [code](fgColor) - 8 does not work (says expected type for value is [code](expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.colors.Color'>). If store and pass color object it works but some of the colors change.

Comment: OK so I dug a bit more and object returned from `cell.fill.fgColor` has 'type' which is set to either 'rgb' or 'indexed'. So I decided to use `cell.fill.fgColor.value` directly and otherwise grab indexed element from `opxl.styles.colors.COLOR_INDEX`. That causes issues because `00000000` occurs in that table more than once. Plus that is just a table associated with OpenPyXL so I presume that workbook that I work on has its own indexed mapping somewhere.

Comment: @TomN to set a color just use: 
cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='f1f1f1', patternType='solid')